# two identical point charges can't collide

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I've convinced myself intuitively that if you place two massless classical particles with the same charge in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with arbitrary initial velocities and (distinct) positions, they will never collide. However, I'm have a heck of a time trying to prove it, and would appreciate some help.

Formally, consider $q_1, q_2: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $$\ddot{q_i} = \frac{1}{\|q_i - q_j\|^3} (q_i - q_j)$$With $q_1(0) \neq q_2(0)$. The claim is that $q_1(t) \neq q_2(t)$ for all $t > 0$.

So my questions are (i) is this true? (ii) what happens if we replace the exponent 3 in the denominator with say $\alpha > 0$ ?

*N.B.* The question's already a bit long, but I'd be happy to post my thoughts so far.

*Edit* All the answers were very helpful, thanks so much everyone!

Comment: Can you show that your system of trajectories has some conserved quantity, like energy, and that this constraint enforces a minimum distance between the two masses? Also it might be easier to work in the centre-of-mass frame.

Comment: Eckhard's approach sounds like the way to go. The worst-case scenario I can imagine is if you fired both particles directly at each other with enormous kinetic energy. As they near each other, that KE gets traded for potential. Actually occupying the same position would imply infinite potential energy, right?

Comment: If your law is to have physical meaning, it must be $n=3$ and in Newton+Coulomb law it's not the norm squared, but to the third power.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Eckhard...let's assume I don't know what energy is, or centre-of-mass. Just Newton's laws. Andrew I agree with the worst-case scenario, the infinite potential energy is a bit worrisome...I suppose the case I want to rule out is that we can't solve the ODE for all time, but until say $t_0$, and $\lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} q_1 - q_2 = 0$ Jorge thanks for the norm squared point, I'm interested in $n \neq 3$ too

Comment: A small point: even though we're talking about physical space, your motion here will be confined to a plane, so $\mathbb{R}^2$ is fine. It's when you get more particles in the mix that things can become more complicated. Still, I think the energy argument here is general. The reason you get "collisions" in particle accelerators is because things like protons aren't actually 'point particles', and what we call a 'collision' is really just 'close enough for their inner constituents to interact nontrivially.'

Comment: "let's assume I don't know what energy is": But knowing Newton's laws you can *derive* the conservation of energy (e.g. [here](http://web.mit.edu/hyouk/www/mites2010/MITES_2010__Physics_III_-_Survey_of_Modern_Physics/MITES_2010__Physics_III_-_Survey_of_Modern_Physics/Entries/2010/6/30_Lecture_5___Classical_mechanics_-_Conservation_of_energy_%28derivation%29_and_small_oscillations_about_equilibrium_position.html)), which I think is @Eckhard's point.

Comment: @Andrew Hmm...the initial positions span at most a plane, but a priori the initial velocities could jolt you out of it no? And thanks for the "collisions" point, trying to think about this is exactly what motivated the question!

Comment: @RahulNarain haha yeah...maybe I should have just written, "I don't know what energy is"...fair enough :p. reading up on it now!

Comment: @uncookedfalcon Nope! Due to the nature of the force involved: it's always directed on a line connecting the two, and those lines span a plane. In order to 'get out' of the plane, you would have to have a force with a component pointing perpendicularly, which can't happen with just two particles using central forces. You need at least 3-body motion in that case. (Notice, however, that something like magnetism is different; you get helical motion, etc. But this is not a central force.)

Comment: @AndrewGibson consider $q_1(0) = (1,0,0), q_2(0) = (0,1,0), \dot{q_1}(0) = (0,0,0), \dot{q_2}(0) = (0,0,N)$ for some $N \gg 0$. I agree with say constant initial velocity we're confined to the plane spanned by $q_1(0), q_2(0)$

Comment: @uncookedfalcon if you wish to analyze the problem in arbitrary dimension, the field is no longer inverse-square dependent.

Comment: @uncookedfalcon I conceded too early before; even in the example you provide, the motion is confined to a plane.

Comment: @AndrewGibson interesting...here's my thinking: by assumption $q_1(0), q_2(0)$ span the $xy$ plane, it suffices to show for some small $t$ that $q_2(t)$ has nonzero last coordinate. I write $q_2$ as $$q_2(t) = q_2(0) + \dot{q}_2(0)t + o(t)$$So its $z$ coordinate is $Nt + o(t)$, which is nonzero for small enough $t$ (by $\epsilon - \delta$) Your thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't suffice to show that -- the plane in question doesn't have to be the (x,y) plane! In fact, it will be slanted in $\mathbb{R}^3$. To understand this more generally, you can move to the center-of-mass frame.

Comment: @AndrewGibson I've found that our "plane", if it's to contain $q_1(0), q_2(0)$ and $q_2(t)$ for $0 \ll t \ll 1$ is supposed to contain $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (?, ?, \neq 0)$, i.e. it's not a plane! I think maybe I've identified our (well, my) source of confusion: when I'm saying plane, this is with respect to the original frame of reference, but you're allowing for a "plane" in an inertial frame moving with nonzero velocity w.r.t. to the original?

Comment: Why can a plane not contain (1,0,0),(0,1,0) and (?,?,$\ne$0) ? These are just three points. Surely you can always find a plane containing any three points... I think you are implicitly assuming that (0,0,0) is in our plane. It's not: neither particle is ever at (0,0,0).

Comment: @AndrewGibson I absolutely was assuming that! Fantastic :)

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: The $ 2 $-dimensional plane that I was referring to moves together with the center-of-mass frame in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $. Of course, if we use some other reference frame, then the trajectories will no longer lie in a single $ 2 $-dimensional plane. This is because the center-of-mass may be undergoing translation as well.

Comment: yes fantastic - this makes good sense (as it does below too!)

Comment: @uncookedfalcon I must apologize, it seems that I was terribly confused. Haskell has cleared things up nicely.

Comment: yeah no worries!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me address the second question. Notice that the electric field is no longer inverse-square dependent in dimensions other than $3$.  The fundamental equation here is $\nabla\cdot \mathbf E=\rho$ (the divergence of the field is the charge density.) In three dimensions the field caused by a point particle will be indeed radial field with magnitude $E(r)=q/4\pi r^2$. In other dimensions the field caused by a point-particle at the origin is still radial but one has $$\mathrm{vol}(S^{n-1})E(r)=\int_{S^{n-1}}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{s} =\int_{n-ball} \,\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E}\,d^{n}x =\int_{n-ball}\rho d^{n}x= q,$$after using Gauss theorem. Then in if you want to consider the field in $\mathbb{R}^n$, its norm is
$$
E(r)=\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{2 \pi^{n/2}}\frac{q}{r^{n-1}}.
$$

Notice that you still get energy conservation. Assuming $1<n\neq 2$,  the potential energy goes as $r^{-(n-2)}$, whereas for $n=2$ the potential goes as $\mathrm{ln}(r)$. Since the charges are initially at different positions, $U_i$, the initial potential energy is finite. Since $T_i+U_i=T_f+E_f$ and the kinetic energy is always positive, you need an infinite initial kinetik energy to make them collide, which is impossible. Then the charges never collide. This answers the first question too, for arbitrary dimension.

Comment: One technicality/question-to apply the analysis of $E$ you provide to the situation at hand, naively I want to use the frame of reference centered at one of the particles, so that the other is now subject to a field on $\mathbb{R}^n - 0$ given by $E$. If this indeed what you had in mind, is it clear that this particle-centered frame of reference is inertial? Thanks!

Comment: @uncookedfalcon Yes, but if you don't like that frame, you can replace $\mathbf{r}$ everywhere by $\mathbf q_1-\mathbf q_2$. The same analysis caries over to this "more general" frame. Regarding your question, both frames are inertial (because setting the force to zero, you get a particle that follows a stright line with constant velocity as the solution to the differential equation). Does that answer your question about frames?

Comment: That absolutely does. Thanks so much!

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: The frame centered at any of the particles *cannot* be inertial. This is because with respect to the inertial center-of-mass frame, each particle is undergoing acceleration due to the mutual repulsion between them.

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: That shouldn’t stop you from adopting a particle-centered frame, but note that non-inertial (fictitious) forces now come into play.

Comment: I agree with Haskell's claim. To clarify, I've been talking only about two inertial frames: $S$, w.r.t which the particles have position $\mathbf q_i$, and $S'$, defined by having the origin at $Q:=(\sum_i m_i \mathbf q_i)/(\sum_i m_i)$. If you write down Newton's second law for $Q$, it's equation of motion is $\ddot{Q}=F_{12}+F_{21}\equiv 0$ (by third law), whence $Q(t)=Vt$ for some constant vector $V$. If one of them is inertial, both are.

Answer (score 4):

By describing all motion with respect to the center-of-mass frame, we can restrict our attention to $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ only. In what follows, $ \mathbf{q}_{1},\mathbf{q}_{2}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ denote the displacement functions of two particles with respect to the center-of-mass frame, where the center-of-mass is fixed at the origin of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $.

For central-force motion involving only two particles, the trajectories $ \mathbf{q}_{1} $ and $ \mathbf{q}_{2} $ are seen to lie strictly within a $ 2 $-dimensional subspace $ \Pi $ of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $. If the affine vectors $ {\dot{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}(0) $ and $ {\dot{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}(0) $ are oriented such that they do not simultaneously point toward/away from the origin, then $ \Pi $ is uniquely determined.

What I have done above is to choose an isometry $ T \in \mathbf{O}(n,\mathbb{R}) $ in order to obtain
$$
T[\Pi] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \underbrace{\{ 0 \} \times \cdots \times \{ 0 \}}_{\text{$ n - 2 $ times}}.
$$
This allows us to shift our focus to $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $. Clearly, the chosen isometrically-linear coordinate transformation does not affect the physics that is being described by the equations of motion specified by the OP above.

With this in mind, note that for $ \alpha = 3 $, what we have is basically the well-studied [Coulomb Collision Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision). Depending on the orientation of the affine vectors $ {\dot{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}(0) $ and $ {\dot{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}(0) $, the trajectories lie in

- non-intersecting hyperbolas or
- non-intersecting segments of a single straight line.

I find it rather interesting that the derivation of the [Rutherford Scattering Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering) in atomic physics relies upon this fact.

For $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \setminus \{ 3 \} $ in general, we no longer have a nice description of the trajectories involved. However, one can easily use an energy-conservation argument to prove that trajectories cannot collide, and this is precisely what Jorge has described in his solution.

Comment: Stupid question re: "the trajectories lie strictly in a 2-dimensional plane of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the initial velocity vectors" - I'm interpreting this is saying $q_i(t) \in \langle \dot{q_i}(0) \rangle$ for all $t$ (in the case $\dot{q_i}(0)$ are linearly independent)...for $t = 0$ why can't I simply pick $q_i(0)$ to be outside of this span?

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: I should have mentioned ‘with respect to the center-of-mass frame’. If you analyze the motion with respect to some other frame, then it is clear that the trajectories will not lie in a single $ 2 $-dimensional plane. :)

Comment: perfect! that does the trick :p

Answer (score 2):

This is as good a place as any to mention how you can derive conservation of energy from scratch, starting with nothing but a differential equation for $\ddot q_i$... as long as your force term is conservative, that is, it is the negative gradient of a scalar "potential energy" function. (I'll deal only with a one-particle system, but you can handle multiple particles simply by packing in all the position variables $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_m$ into a single vector in $\mathbb R^{mn}$.)

Consider $\ddot q=f(q)$ where $f$ is conservative, i.e. $f(q) = -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq} U(q)$ for some scalar-valued potential $U$. Introduce a momentum variable $p=\dot q$ so that $\dot p = f(q).$ Observe that $p = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dp} T(p)$ where $T(p) = \frac12\lVert p\rVert^2$. Define the energy function $H(q,p) = U(q) + T(p)$, and observe that
$$\dot H(q,p) = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\cdot\dot q + \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\cdot\dot p = -\dot p\cdot\dot q + \dot q\cdot\dot p = 0,$$
so $H$ is constant over time for any solution.

For your problem, your $U(q_1,q_2)$ will depend only on $\lVert q_1-q_2\rVert$, and you'll want to check whether $H$ is infinite in a colliding configuration. I think you need $\alpha>1$ for that to happen.

Comment: Thanks writing this out! However, I still can't see how to apply the case of particles moving in a conservative field to the case at hand. The only way I could see to do it would be to take the frame of reference of say $q_1$, but I somehow doubt that this frame is inertial. Do you have any thoughts on this? (this is identical to my comment on Jorge's answer)

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: Suppose $U(q_1,q_2)=a \lVert q_1-q_2\rVert^b$ for some unknown $a$ and $b$. Compute $-\frac{\partial}{\partial q_1}U(q_1,q_2)$ and compare with your desired force $(q_1-q_2)/\lVert q_1-q_2\rVert^\alpha$.